# problem in update text item

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I Have problem in update one of my datablock textitem.

the problem will raise up because I use where condition for my datablock,and after I load the data block, I try to get new value to my text item,but after I put value there is no change...

I dont know how I can change a text item database value when my block has where condition.(the problem is it replace the value with database value.

I use oracle 6i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query in a block, Oracle Forms first clears the block before it populates it with the data retrieved from the database.

If you want to change what is shown in the database item after the query is done, you would normally add code to the POST-QUERY trigger on the block. This trigger fires once for each record retrieved from the database.